# Dart Flutter Firebase FirebaseException ([cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have permission to execute the specified operation.)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in my `main.dart` file:

```
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  await firestore.collection("oneSignal").add(
    {
      "id": "testing"
    }
  );
```

When I run the codes, I get an error like this:

[image]

What is the problem? How can I solve it?

---

[image]

---

Apart from the `main.dart` file, I also have a file related to Firebase:

For Firebase, apart from the main.dart file, I also have a file called firebase_options.dart. It contains many IDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In firebase security is handled by security rules, it's a tab in your firestore firebase console. Check there if your caller (authenticated or not authenicated) is able to do write operation into oneSignal collection

For authenticated

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /oneSignal/{signalId} {
        allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

For unauthenticated

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /oneSignal/{signalId} {
        allow write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Should I put this code in main.dart or firabase_settings.dart?

Also, what is the difference between authenticated and unauthenticated?

Thanks.

Comment: @EmirBolat I recommend reading the Firebase documentation about its server-side security rules, both [overall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/get-started) and specific to [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I tried both of the codes you provided. I added it to Rules from Firebase. But still the same problem exists.

Comment: @Dominik: that comment is probably for you :)

Comment: I also tried printing data to test the FireBase connection, I was able to write data to the `oneSignal` collection without any problems. I am waiting for your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: @EmirBolat you was able to write data? Than I don't much understand what is the problem now. You had problem writing dont you? Now you are saying that you was able to write data without any problems
Dont you have problem now with reading data, cause its blocked now with security rules?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71550352/how-to-get-value-of-data-retrieved-from-dart-flutter-firebase/71550685#71550685

Comment: Well that's totally different problem than you asked