# How to get value of data retrieved from Dart Flutter Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a code like this:

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  FirebaseFirestore FS = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  CollectionReference TC = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("oneSignal");
  var docs = TC.doc("xcG9kfCWnUK7QKbK37qd");
  var response = await docs.get();
  
  var veriable = response.data();
  print(veriable);
```

I'm getting an output like this:

```
{id: 5138523951385235825832}
```

I only want the value from this output, namely `5138523951385235825832`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `response` is a `DocumentSnapshot`, so `response.data()` returns a `Map` with all the fields. To get a specific field from it you can do:

```
var veriable = response.data() as Map;
print(veriable["id"]);
```

Alternatively you can get the field directly from the response with:

```
print(response.get("id"));
```

For situations like that I recommend keeping the documentation handy, in this case for [`DocumentSnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

`response.data()` returns a Map. A Map is a key-value pair.
In Dart value of a Map can be accessed using a key.

```
void main() { 
   var details = {'Usrname':'tom','Password':'pass@123'}; 
   details['Uid'] = 'U1oo1'; 
   print(details); 
}
```

It will produce the following output −

```
{Usrname: tom, Password: pass@123, Uid: U1oo1}
```

In your case, you can get the value of id using `veriable['id']`